# Weird circle looking like coffee stain on windows

Tags: cycles-render-engine, add-on

I'm making my first project and realised I got a weird circle on the glass on my windows looking like a coffee stain or something (the circle only appears on the windows). I don't know when it appeared and if it helps at all I'm using windows from the Archipack add-on.

Thank's for any help! I'll link some pictures.

[image: Weird circle on window]

[image: Weird circle on window zoomed in]

[image]

Comment: hello, are you sure there's not an object than is invisible in preview but visible in render?

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer. Yeah, the circle is visible in the preview aswell. when I move the circle change place on the windows.

Comment: If you can move the circle, why not simply delete it or hide it in rendered view so that it's no longer visible?

Comment: Sorry I might have worded that wrong, when I move the camera* the circle change position on the window. I can't move the circle and it's not  an object (I think).

Comment: I'm guessing it has to do with the IOR of your glass. Since windows are flat, I think you can get away with setting the value as low as 1.05 or so. Does that make the circle disappear?

Comment: maybe provide your blend file so we can check it out?

Comment: Yeah I tried to set the IOR to 1.05 and the circle disappeared but it also made the glass into a mirror haha. I also tried lowering the IOR bit by bit and it seems to make the circle bigger and bigger until the glass becomes said mirror.

Comment: Alright let me figure out how to share the blend file

Comment: There I edited the post with a Blend-Exchange file.

Answer (score 2):

The circle is a reflection of the object **Plane.005**, which is the empty room behind the camera. For whatever reason, the material has a *Background* set to black as a surface instead of a *Principled BSDF*, *Diffuse BSDF* or any other "real" object shader and I was wondering why it's not reflected as black room inside the window.

Then I looked at the glass material of the window and saw that there is a *Fresnel* node set to 40(!) as mix factor between a *Glossy BSDF* and a *Transparent BSDF*. This causes the reflection to somehow distort spherical between the front and back face of the glass. You can see that more clearly if you change the material of Plane.005 to white for example, you have simple reflection on the front face and the sphere on the backface - the IOR makes the reflection bend that much inside the glass.

When I set the IOR to something "normal" like 1.45, the window simply (strongly) reflects a pitch black room like a mirror, that's because there is a *Glossy BSDF* in there instead of a *Glass BSDF*. So the IOR is definitely way off. I don't know why the Archipack window has such a strange material... When I simply delete all nodes and put a *Glass BSDF* in there instead of this complex node setup, there is no circle and no mirrored pitch black room.

Comment: Hey, thank you so much! Im new to all this and what I learned is if I use a normal Glass BSDF the room will be filled with a lot of noise. I used the glass recommended by blender guru and clearly must have missed a step :D. Thank you so much again for that answer!

Comment: @Alex Yes, interiors are always problematic with noise etc. when you use real glass materials. If I don't care for realistic reflections of the interior on the windows, for a simple solution I put no window in there and use only the frame in the render. Or take a mix shader to make the glass only visible for the camera and completely transparent to the scene.